# Python: List comprehension not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Below is part of a learning process and any help is really appreciated!

I am having an issue reverse engineering a list comprehension. I have a list of input data:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

And I want to create a new series of lists to look like:

```
['apples', 'Alice', 'dogs']
['oranges', 'Bob', 'cats']
['cherries', 'Carol', 'moose']
['banana', 'David', 'goose']
```

I can do this using:

```
i = 0
for li in range(4):
    out = [item[i] for item in tableData]
    print(out)
    i += 1
```

However, when I try and use:

```
i = 0
out = []
for li in range(4):
    for item in tableData:
        out.append(item[i])
        print(out)
        i += 1
```

It causes an error.

Any idea why? How can I get this to work like the former example?

Comment: longestzip() should do it

Comment: For future reference, "It causes an error." is not very useful for solving your issue.  Posting the exact error you get (ie. `IndexError: list index out of range`) would be much more useful for us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind the error has been quoted by @Matt B.

However, an effient approach here could be:

Using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
print(list(zip_longest(tableData[0],tableData[1], tableData[2])))
```

or even better, generalized. (Thanks to @Patrick Haugh)

```
print(list(zip_longest(*tableData)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[('apples', 'Alice', 'dogs'), ('oranges', 'Bob', 'cats'), ('cherries', 'Carol', 'moose'), ('banana', 'David', 'goose')]
```

> Note, I used `zip_longest` and not `zip` to take care of the extra
>   elements, Incase of data like (Notice the `red apples` and `Elon`):

```
tableData = [['red apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David', 'Elon'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

Using `zip` would miss the `banana` and `Elon` giving an output:

```
[('red apples', 'Alice', 'dogs'), ('apples', 'Bob', 'cats'), ('oranges', 'Carol', 'moose'), ('cherries', 'David', 'goose')]
```

But using `longest_zip` would insert the missing values as `None`:

```
[('red apples', 'Alice', 'dogs'), ('apples', 'Bob', 'cats'), ('oranges', 'Carol', 'moose'), ('cherries', 'David', 'goose'), ('banana', 'Elon', None)]
```

Comment: This can be generalized by using unpacking `list(zip(*tableData))`

Comment: This is great! And thanks for the extra info you added, really useful knowledge!

Comment: @JKRH no worries, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 4):

It throws an error because you make a loop 4 times (`range(4)`) to loop over `tableData` which has only 3 elements inside.

```
i = 0
out = []
for li in range(3): # <<< Change to 3
    for item in tableData:
        out.append(item[i])
        print(out)
        i += 1
```

What would be better would be to loop over the `range` of the `len` of `tableData`, this way it behaves dynamically and you can change the length of `tableData` without it throwing what I assume was an `IndexError`:

```
i = 0
out = []
for li in range(len(tableData))
    for item in tableData:
        out.append(item[i])
        print(out)
        i += 1
```

Comment: This still causes a problem as the list output produces: 
['apples']
['apples', 'Bob']
['apples', 'Bob', 'moose']
['apples', 'Bob', 'moose', 'banana']
Then throws:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This will only fix the error you are experiencing, I would suggest using @DirtyBit 's excellent solution to obtain the output you want

Comment: Hi, thanks again. As I said, I am just trying to work out how Python functions (super newbie!), so it is less about trying to find the solution and more about finding how the method works.
That said, @DirtyBit's solution was great and has been added into my book of useful code snippets!
Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I remember answering a question on the same dataset yesterday (about finding the longest word in the list), I assumed you are playing around trying to understand better how Python works so thought I'd give just the info on the error you're getting and let you work out the rest ;)

Comment: Yep, that was me as well. It is a practice question out of Automate The Boring Stuff (great book). Just trying to get my head around the theory and get used to writing code. Really enjoying the challenge, as well as all the help from people on this forum! Hopefully one day I'll be able to give back as well!

Answer (score 4):

If you want the lists inside of `tableData` printed out, then you could just write:

```
for item in tableData:
    print(item)
```

Matt B's example:

```
 i = 0
    out = []
    for li in range(len(tableData)):
        for item in tableData:
            out.append(item[i])
            print(out)
            i += 1
```

This will also cause an error because `i` will get out of bounds.
You would not have to initialize `i`, you could just append with `item`.

```
 out = []
 # No nested for loop. this will cause duplicates of the list
 for item in tableData:
      out.append(item) #<<< No need for item[i]
 print(out)
```

If you already have a list of lists then you don't need to make a new list of lists.